# Software key and hardware tracking solution

Tags: asset-management

I am looking for a better way to track our hardware inventory and our software keys. Currently we are using an Openoffice a spreadsheet paired with CVS for revision control. As our company has grown, this sheet has grown as well. To the point where it is out of control and hard to find anything without using "find". We do not need anything expensive or elaborate. I am just looking for suggestions. I would like it to meet the following conditions.

1. Opensource or free for corporate use
2. can track hardware inventory
3. can track software keys and users
4. can run on linux preferably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had my <s>minion</s> new admin setup OCS inventory ( http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/ ) with clients installed and running on user desktops. Server clients have been compiled and run once, though not added to cron (yet).

Because the OCS interface is rubbish and looks like a 4 year old drew it with crayons (no offense to any OCS people who read this - the actual software is great), we're using GLPI for the actual interface ( http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/OCS-GLPI-en ).

It runs smoothly on a LAMP stack and we've had no problems with it yet.

Comment: OCS + GLPI is great for this. Add WPKG to easily deploying software on computers.